# Computing next prefix index in KMP implementations

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

I've read through a number of different implementations of KMP and can't quite figure out one aspect they all share.

When they compute the longest prefix which is also suffix-array (lps). 
If the characters do not match at the indexes tested at a specific iteration, and the index of the prefix is not 0. The index of the prefix is set to

> index = lps[index - 1];

Here is an example

```
void computeLPSArray(String pat, int M, int lps[])
{
    // length of the previous longest prefix suffix
    int len = 0;
    int i = 1;
    lps[0] = 0;  // lps[0] is always 0

    // the loop calculates lps[i] for i = 1 to M-1
    while (i < M)
    {
        if (pat.charAt(i) == pat.charAt(len))
        {
            len++;
            lps[i] = len;
            i++;
        }
        else  // (pat[i] != pat[len])
        {
            // This is tricky. Consider the example.
            // AAACAAAA and i = 7. The idea is similar 
            // to search step.
            if (len != 0)
            {
                len = lps[len-1];

                // Also, note that we do not increment
                // i here
            }
            else  // if (len == 0)
            {
                lps[i] = len;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any situation where *index = lps[index-1]* is not equivalent to

> index--;